# How to add a menu item into Visual Studio 6.0 IDE with an Addin developed in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, add-in, menuitem, visual-c++-6

How to add a menu item into Visual Studio 6.0 IDE from an Addin developed in Visual C++ 6.0?

When we create a simple Addin using the Visual Studio Add-In wizard, it adds a tool bar button but not a menu item!
I only found articles about C# and Visual Basic that use classes, such as CommandBarPopup, which is unavailable in Visual C++ 6.0.

Please, note that I don't wanna anything related to .NET and/or macros.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Visual Studio version number right? VS 6.0 is almost 15 years old.

Comment: I have 2010 and 6.0, but at this moment I wanna work with 6.0.